# mapbox gl fill-extrusion-height restriction decimal values in meter

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I was trying to model a detailed building with fill-extrusion feature of mapbox, but I experienced that it takes height in multiplication of 1 meter only.

Please see this JSFiddle:

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/parveenkaloi/p5w1je7s/20/`
```

I've set 9 boxes in these sizes (meters):

1: 0.25m,

2: 0.5m,

3: 0.75m,

4: 1.0m,

5: 1.25m,

6: 1.5m,

7: 1.75m,

8: 2.0m,

9: 2.25m

but in result height is :

1: 0.0m,

2: 0.0m,

3: 0.0m,

4: 1.0m,

5: 1.0m,

6: 1.0m,

7: 1.0m,

8: 2.0m,

9: 2.0m

Please help me, if there is any solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example -  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sure, will care in future....
Please see this updated JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/parveenkaloi/p5w1je7s/34/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the old version of the `mapbox-gl-js` library - v0.38.0. Try latest v0.47.0.

There is also a shorter record for obtaining values - via expressions:

```
"paint": {
  'fill-extrusion-color':  ["get", "clr"],
  'fill-extrusion-height': ["get", "ht" ],
  'fill-extrusion-base':   ["get", "pz" ]
}
```

[ http://jsfiddle.net/n3zvs9jm/1/ ]